# How to display static resource image in visual force component?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have uploaded image to static resource. i just want to display it on the visual force component `<apex:component>` . i tried this way

```html
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.myResourceImage}" width="200" height="200"/>
```

but the image still is not rendering in the UI.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the image doesn't show up in the email is because value="{!$Resource.myResourceImage}" generates a relative URL from which the image is rendered (i.e. "/resource/1312483024000/logo"). This URL is accessible only for authenticated platform users.

To solve this problem, images should be stored in documents and with "Externally Available Image" checked. The image will be available by using the following markup:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id>" width="200" height="200"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello below code is working for me
Please try this

```
<apex:page >
<apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.vfimagetest,'cats/kitten1.jpg')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i have tried  this approach already like <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.track)}"/>  but it is not working. here track is static resource file name

Comment: give the image path also , check my example 'vfimagetest' is my zipped file and after that i gave image path 'cats/kitten1.jpg' , here cat is folder in zip file

Comment: dont know some how , it is not working in my environment. need to find the alternative way